# Writing Configured instances for Configurator

Tags: haskell

I am using Bryan O'Sullivan's `Configurator` library to provide database connection details. `app.cfg` contains the following

```
database {
  host = "localhost"
  port = 5432
  user = "mydb"
  db = "mydb_dev"
  password = ""
}
```

In my Haskell code, I have a corresponding data type, i.e.

```
data DBConnection = DBConnection 
  { host :: Text
  , port :: Int
  , user :: Text
  , database :: Text
  , password :: Text
  } deriving Show
```

I am unsure how I would go about writing an instance of `Configured` for this type.

Clearly I can use `lookup` to access each element of the database config, getting `IO Maybe a`, and then construct from these values but is it possible to shift this into a typeclass instance?

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: From the API exposed, it doesn't really appear you can do that.  Unfortunately, the `Configured` class only converts from the `Value` type, which can only hold `Bool`, `Text`, `Rational`, or lists of those values, it doesn't support more complicated structures like `aeson` does.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a type class? It's easy enough to extract the config manually:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Configurator

getDBConnection :: Config -> IO DBConnection
getDBConnection cfg = DBConnection
    <$> get "host"
    <*> get "port"
    <*> get "db"
    <*> get "user"
    <*> get "password"
  where
    get :: Configured a => Name -> IO a
    get = require cfg
```

If you don't like exceptions, here's a `Maybe` version:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Data.Configurator

getDBConnection :: Config -> IO (Maybe DBConnection)
getDBConnection cfg = runMaybeT $ DBConnection
    <$> get "host"
    <*> get "port"
    <*> get "db"
    <*> get "user"
    <*> get "password"
  where
    get :: Configured a => Name -> MaybeT IO a
    get = MaybeT . lookup cfg
```

There's really no need to overcomplicate things. It's just ten lines of code.